# How to ouput ftype path only to .txt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-association

I have a known filetype (blendfile) and I want to write the associated application path into a .txt file (in the same folder as the batch script).

So for example, for a .txt file I'm using:
`ftype blendfile >> "%~dp1BlenderPath.txt"`

Which gives me an output of:
`blendfile="C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\blender.exe" "%1"`

But I only want the `"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\blender.exe"` part written into the text file.
How do I achieve this?

(EDIT: Edited question to be specific to the filetype path I was looking for)

Comment: Please can you provide a genuine task to go along with this question. The question shows `txtfile` and provides its pre-modified output. Your comment beneath the existing answer asks about `blendfile` and complains about the result, despite the fact you didn't mention it, or provide its output, in your question. If you are hoping to use a solution which you can provide any `fileType`, you need to at least make an attempt at the question yourself, because all `openCommandString`'s are not just a file path, and, as you've not attempted it yourself, your question becomes an off topic code request

Comment: Just open a Command Prompt window, type `ftype|more`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and take a look at some of the outputs each `fileType` can hold, _(use the spacebar to move down a page)_.

Comment: Point noted @Compo, I'll edit the question (didn't realise the differences in outputs for ftype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the blendfile, try:

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=1^,2delims^=^=^" %%i in ('ftype blendfile') do echo "%%~j"
```

`ftype` stores various formats, so this particular item will not work for all `ftype` entries.

So to get all of the ftype values, you need a bit of a hack. For the amount of time I have, this is the best I can do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f tokens^=1^,2*delims^=^=^/^" %%i in ('ftype') do (
   set "str=%%~j"
   set "str=!str: %%1=!"
   set  str="!str!"
   set  "str=!str: "="!"
   echo !str!
  )
)>"%~dp1BlenderPath.txt"
```

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect my initial goal, I hadn't realised the complications with varying path outputs...  I'll mark your answer as correct, (if you want edit your answer for only the blendfile path)... but feel free to add an answer to cover all path types if you discovered how!

Comment: You must also just let me know what the result is, keep in mind we do not all have the same environments and software installed, so the results may vary.

Comment: You're hack seems to work mostly. But it also output multiples of the same path for some programs (eg. `"C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe"` was written about 20 times). Thanks for helping with the original question, that was my only goal at the moment, I had assumed incorrectly that there would be a generic command to output only the path of any application.

Comment: Yes, it will, because the variable's differ. have a look at the variable before the value when you run  the command `ftype | findstr "iTunes"`. so `iTunes.m4p=iTunes` and `iTunes.m4b=iTunes` that is how they are registered.